# Can't route to correct component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Not sure if I'm setting my routing up correctly.
I can't seem to route to the 'MemberEditComponent' using

```
[routerLink]="['/members/edit']"
```

Here is my app-routing section for my members module

```js
{
  path: 'members',
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('./members/members.module')
    .then(mod => mod.MembersModule)
},
```

Here is my members-routing file, where routing to members works fine and routing to
'/members/1' works fine, but I can't figure out how to route to
'/members/edit'

I tried both

> path: ':edit',

and

> path: '/edit',

and

> path: 'edit',

and none work

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MembersComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: MemberDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: MemberDetailResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: ':edit',
    component: MemberEditComponent,
    canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]
  },
];
```

Comment: When You pass the mouse over your link, is It poiting to address/members/edit or address/edit ?

Comment: yes. Shouldn't it route me to the angular component first? Because there is an exception being thrown in my controller in the exception middleware. It seems as if it's trying to call my controller first and not route to the angular compnent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, in your route, you have specified 2 parameters that are of can be read the same so by default if you access `/members/edit`, it will first land to your `MemberDetailsComponent` as angular treats your `/edit` as the `:id` parameter of `MemeberDetailsComponent`

```
{
    path: ':id',
    component: MemberDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: MemberDetailResolver
    }
  },
{
    path: ':edit',
    component: MemberEditComponent,
    canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]
},
```

Instead, you can implement it like this:

```
{
    path: 'edit',                                   // without :, so this will be matched first if the route has /edit in it
                                                    // or edit/:id if you are editing something in this component
    component: MemberEditComponent,
    canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]
},
{
    path: ':id',
    component: MemberDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: MemberDetailResolver
    }
},
```